# Get the name of the Helm subchart in the umbrella chart

Tags: yaml, dependencies, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a subchart in the chart dependencies defined as:

```
dependencies:
  - condition: myTestSubchart.enabled
    name: my-test-subchart
    repository: oci://harbor.test.com/helm
    version: 0.1.0
    alias: myTestSubchart
```

The `alias` is defined as we cannot reference on the names with dashes in the yaml.
However, using alias, we do not get the correct name of the subchart.

For example `{{ template "my-test-subchart.name" .Subcharts.myTestSubchart }}` will produce `myTestSubchart` instead of `my-test-subchart`, I understand this is because of the alias of the dependent subchart.

The template is default one:

```
{{/*
Expand the name of the chart.
*/}}
{{- define "my-test-subchart.name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
```

But I need to have an alias, because of the yaml convention.

One of the solution I do not like very much is to override the name back in the `values.yaml` of the umbrella chart like this:

```
myTestSubchart:
  nameOverride: my-test-subchart
```

This will produce expected `my-test-subchart` from `{{ template "my-test-subchart.name" .Subcharts.myTestSubchart }}`.

However, it is hardcoded in the values of the umbrella chart.

Is there any solution for that without overriding values?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same. The following works for me:

> The alias is defined as we cannot reference on the names with dashes in the yaml.

One can use the [sprig template functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) for this, which are part of [helm templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dictionaries-and-dict-functions).

Remove the alias. Instead of:

```
{{ template "my-test-subchart.name" .Subcharts.myTestSubchart }}
```

use:

```
{{ include "my-test-subchart.name" (get .Subcharts "my-test-subchart") }}
```

This should give you the name from the chart definition.